# eigenvector transformation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Say you have the following matrix A in $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -10 \\
5 & -8
\end{bmatrix}
$

Thus the eigenvalues/eigenvectors are: 2 $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and -3 $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Thus the eigenspace matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Say you have the vector v(x,y) of (2,3), thus Ax = [-16, -14].

I'm confused as to how does the eigenspace and eigenvalues allow me to easily see what A is doing to the vector (2,3)?

How do I apply the eigenvalues/eigenspace on vector v(2,3) to see what A is doing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write $(2,3)$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors.

In this case, $(2,3) = -(2,1) + 4 (1,1)$, so
$$A \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = - A  \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + 4 A  \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and then you can use the fact that these are eigenvectors to easily complete the computation and understand how the "stretching" along the two "eigen-directions" describes the action of $A$ on $(2,3)$.

More generally, you should read about diagonalizing $A$.

Comment: Thanks very helpful, but what would diagnolizing A give me?  Ax(2,3) = $PDP^{-1}$*(2,3) but I would still need to compute P and $P^{-1}$ to find out the transformation on the vector (2,3) given that D = [2 0 | 0 -3]?

Comment: @PEBguy What I described essentially boils down to diagonalization. "Writing $(2,3)$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors" is basically $P^{-1} (2,3)$, and so on.

Comment: ah got it, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that $A(2,1) = 2(2,1)$ and $A(1,1) = -3(1,1)$ by def of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Can you write the desired vector $(2,3)$ as a linear combination of $(2,1)$ and $(1,1)$?  Note that $-1(2,1)+4(1,1) = (2,3)$.

Hence, you can simplify the calculation to
$$A(2,3) = -1*2*(2,1)+4*(-3)*(1,1) = (-4,-2)-(12,12) = (-16,-14).$$